# Replacing values in a multi-index dataframe column with a calculated value

Tags: python, replace, dataframe, calculated-columns

I want to do Gauss normalization on a set of values (it is normalization by the business ranked and by the rank of reviewers). Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = ['user_id','business_id', 'stars']
data = {'user_id': ['u1', 'u1', 'u2', 'u1', 'u2', 'u2', 'u2', 'u1'],
    'business_id': ['r1', 'r2', 'r2', 'r2', 'r1', 'r2', 'r1', 'r1'],
    'stars': [5.0, 3.0, 2.0, 4.0, 1.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0],
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

userList = set(df.user_id)
busList = set(df.business_id)


for user_id in userList:
    # average rating given by the user
    avg_user = df[df.user_id == user_id].stars.mean()
    sum = 0.0  
    for bus_id in busList:

        sum += (df[(df.user_id == user_id) & (df.business_id == bus_id)].stars.values - avg_user)**2

    for bus_id2 in busList:

        rating = (df[(df.user_id == user_id) & (df.business_id == bus_id2)].stars.values - avg_user) / sum

        df[(df.user_id == user_id) & (df.business_id == bus_id2)].stars = rating
```

busList - is a list of business IDs
userList - a list of user IDs

1. I think I have way too many loops but I can not figure out a way to reduce their number. Need an advice
2. My last line of code, where I am replacing the values in the column "stars" with a calculated value "rating" seems very bulky. Any suggestions?
3. When I print sum after every cycle I get weird for me results:

   [ 2.  0.]  - must be 2.0 for u1 (sum of these 2 numbers)

   [ 2.5  6.5] - must be 9 for u2 (sum of these 2 numbers)

I just feel that the code is bulky and I am doing something wrong

Thank you!

Comment: If you provide test data your question will be answered more likely

Comment: hard to tell  but maybe `apply` might help

Comment: @Moritz - added test data and some initial code

Comment: @pbreach - It worked! Wow! Just changing the sequence stars and user_id did the trick! I am new to Python and the use of [ ] and the sequence of the criteria puzzle me very often. Why did this work?